# Remove double back slash in a string

Tags: c#, php

Hi After parsing a file using c# parse we are getting json with a string contains `"SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\\O CALDWELL AND KERR"` but the original file contains only single slash

We are trying to remove the extra back slash either using c# or php but can't able to do it. Any help from fellow developers

Answer (score 0):

In C#:

```
string RemoveDuplicateBackslashes(string theString)
{
    while (theString.Contains(@"\\"))
        theString = theString.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
    return theString;
}
```

In PHP:

```
function removeDuplicateBackslashes($theString)
{
    while (strpos($theString, "\\\\") !== false)
        $theString = str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $theString);
    return $theString;
}
```

Comment: i can get any number of slashes

Comment: solution has to be generic

Answer (score 0):

In case of any number of slases you can use `Regex.Replace` method:

```
public string ReplaceSlashes(string source) 
{
    var pattern = @"\\+";

    return Regex.Replace(source, pattern, @"\");
}
```

the results are:

```
ReplaceSlashes(@"SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\O CALDWELL AND KERR"); // SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\O CALDWELL AND KERR
ReplaceSlashes(@"SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\\O CALDWELL AND KERR"); // SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\O CALDWELL AND KERR
ReplaceSlashes(@"SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\\\\\\\\O CALDWELL AND KERR"); // SOUTH MOTOR COMPANY C\O CALDWELL AND KERR
```